# PHP contact form error

Tags: php

Have the following for my contact form im building only its not sending...

Ive tried to print the results to the browser which it does but for some reason it wont send, can anybody see syntax errors?

```
<?php 

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$addr = $_POST['addr'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$landline = $_POST['landline'];
$mob = $_POST['mob'];
$carw = $_POST['carw'];
$depo = $_POST['depo'];
$marsta = $_POST['marsta'];
$ressta = $_POST['ressta'];
$to = "liam@.co.uk";

    //begin of HTML message
    $message = "
  From : $name $lname,
  Email: $email,
  Address: $addr $postcode,
  Landline: $landline,
  Mobile: $mob,
  Car Wanted: $carw,
  Deposit Available: $depo,
  Marital Status: $marsta,
  Residential Status: $ressta";
   //end of message

    // To send the HTML mail we need to set the Content-type header.
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0rn";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1rn";
    $headers  .= "From: Website Enquiry";




if (isset($name))
{
       // now lets send the email.
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '?e=Thankyou, we will be in touch shortly.');

} else {header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '?e=There was an error sending your message, Please try again.');}

?>
```

Comment: Don't build mime messages yourself. Use swiftmailer or phpmailer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `rn`, use `\r\n`.

URL encode your `Location:` header data.  URLs do not have spaces.

Also, consider that not everyone can read HTML e-mail.  Send a text version in addition to the HTML version.

Finally, you might not want to send such an open-ended e-mail, as you can be easily used by spammers with this script.

Comment: @Liam, See MetalFrog's answer.

Comment: +1 for code improvement suggestions. Wouldn't hurt to have a little input validation either.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it doesn't work is that you're checking if `$name` is set, and it clearly is not. You have an `$fname` though.